# Reading file directly from folder in php

Tags: php, html, css, web

I want my code to read the file(image) from directly from the folder. But only one file(image) it read and still reading it again (infinity) it didn't stop display one same file(image). But not all the other five different files (image).

```
<?php

    $dir_path = "image/gundam/";
    $extensions_array = array('jpg','png','jpeg');

    if(is_dir($dir_path)){
         $files = scandir($dir_path);

         for($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++){
             while($files[$i] !='.' && $files[$i] !='..'){
                  // get file name
                  echo "File Name -> $files[$i]<br>";

                  // get file extension
                  $file = pathinfo($files[$i]);
                  $extension = $file['extension'];
                  echo "File Extension-> $extension<br>";

                  // check file extension
                  if(in_array($extension, $extensions_array)){
                  // show image
                      echo "<img src='$dir_path$files[$i]' style='width:100px;height:100px;'><br>";
                  }
              }
          }
     }
 ?>
```

Comment: so you want to display all image in that folder?

Comment: yes i want to display all the image from the folder

Answer (score 0):

This works for me , i tested locally, You don't need to for loop to do this

```
$dir = 'var/images/';
$extensions = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');

if( false !== is_dir($dir) ) {

    $dir_contents = scandir( $dir );

    foreach($dir_contents as $images) {

        $file_ext = pathinfo($images, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if( ($images !== '.') && 
            ($images !== '..') && 
            (in_array($file_ext,$extensions))

        ) {

            echo "<img src='$dir$images' style='width:100px;height:100px;'><br>";

        }
    }

} else {

    echo "Path is not directory";

}
```

Comment: Thank you guys for the help, I just try and error yesterday. The only problem is change    `while` to `if`.

Answer (score 0):

To be very specific to your problem, You could use `GLOB` to find out the files in the folder and then match them against your extension list and then display the images. you could use the following code to display all images with specific extension in a given folder.

```
$FILES = glob($PATH."/*.*");
for ($i=0; $i<count($FILES); $i++) {
    $fileName = $FILES[$i];
    $fileExtension = strtolower(pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    if (in_array($fileExtension, $ALLOWEDTYPES)) {
        echo "<img style='margin: 10px auto' height='150' width='150' src='".$fileName ."' alt='".$fileName."' />";
    } else {
        continue;
    }
}
```

generally speaking, you could also use a scandir as the other user mentioned in post above to achieve similar result to display all the images from a given folder.

```
$FILES = scandir($PATH);
foreach ($FILES as $index => $imageUrl) {
    echo "<img style='margin: 10px auto' height='150' width='150' src='".$PATH."/".$imageUrl."' alt='".$imageUrl."' />";
}
```

I have a working example hosted on phpsandbox here: https://phpsandbox.io/n/lucky-pond-poov